# How to use associations in views correctly?

Tags: php, model, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I want to make simple output. This is part of list.phtml:

```
// more code
<td>
    <a href="<?=$this->url('news', array('action'=>'full', 'id' => $item['id']));?>"><?=$item['title'];?></a> 
</td>
<td>
    <?=$item['category']->getName();?>
</td>
<td>
    <?=$item['user']->getDisplayName();?>
</td>
// more code
```

As you see I am outputting name in `a` tag, category name and user name. I am working with models, so `$item['category']` is object of class `Category` and `$item['user']` is object of class User.

The question is it correct get values this way or should I do it in controller or somehow else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the entire object to your view and calling its methods there, return an array in your controller action that has the exact view variables that you will need to use in your view file.

Like this:

```
class FooController extends FooClass
{
    public function listAction()
    {
        // do stuff

        // setting view variables
        return array(
            'category_name' => $your_object->getName(),
            'display_name'  => $your_object2->getDisplayName()
        );
    }
}
```

That way in your view file all you have to do is:

```
<td>
    <?php echo $this->category_name;?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php echo $this->display_name;?>
</td>
```

Comment: Yes, but what about other fiels? I will use `category_name`, `display_name` and `$item['fieldname']`? It is dirty too, isn't it?

Comment: If you're using that same list in other files, then it would best be put in a view partial. If you're needing the logic of the model in all of the actions in your controller then you might look into overwriting the setEventManager in your controller so you're so not rewriting the same thing for each action.

Comment: No, I am not using same list in many actions. I just said, that it is not beautiful solution and that's all.

Comment: What isn't a "beautiful" solution? My answer?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is same as mine, but you get values in controller.

Comment: It's not the same as yours. And that is the purpose of the controller, to set your values there, your view files are for displaying info, not calling a bunch of methods from your object. Also, if you want it to be "beautiful" I could paste some pink flowers into the code. Good luck.

Comment: Model -> provides data from bussinesslogic(object) to Controller -> prepares/alters data to the View -> render/show data. Simple mvc pattern. In your given question you just skipped the controller part so your aproach is definetly diffrent from @alex.

Comment: @cptnk yes, I watched to the problem from another point of view. I had my "wheel", alex suggested "wheel" but from different angel, as I thought. Now I understand, that it is same "wheel", but it is better "wheel", because now it is mvc :). What about pink flowers :D :D I think it is mine bad english. I meant... ah I don't know how to say :))) Do you know [this](http://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670) book? It shows how to write good code. I thought my code was not good and alex's code was same. Do you understand now :)

Comment: @SharikovVladislav yes I do get your point. I came of a litle harsh I think I did not mean to say your aproach was bad or wrong. I just ment it wasn't the same as alex's in my opinion. Also I honestly do not know what the "cleanest" way of passing variables to view's is. I usually see alot of array_exchange methods in Entities when browsing the official documentation and album app. They just build the array's in the controller and pass those. This aproach may be the cleanest but im not 100% sure.

Comment: @cptnk hm, you just said about entities... May be it is not bad idea, to write function on model, which will provide _final_ data. _Final_ means, that user will be not instance of User class, but name of user and category will be not instance of Category class, but name of category. I read somewhere such opinion... Nice idea :) Thank you very much.